# How to send html mail in drupal 8 rules

Tags: drupal-8, drupal-rules

I want to use rules module to send the HTML mail, directly form the UI, But in drupal 8 send mail action only shows Send Message body as text field.

[image]

Can I use it to send the HTML mail directly like can I use default CKeditor or dynamic mail template to send a for specific purpose, I want to use it with different token parameters to send at bulk using some action.

Thanks.

Comment: See https://www.drupal.org/project/mimemail, it has integration with the rules module.

Comment: Thanks for reply, I have mimemail install and able to send html mail, but not with rules modules - not getting any option on "Send Mail" option on rules

Comment: I am also having same issue. I have installed both Rules as well as mimemail modules, but not getting option to send HTML mail.

Comment: @FarhanErooth, I found a programmatically way to send html emails from website and embed that to project.